# Integral Surface Passing through a curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Find the integral surface of the partial differential equation $(x^2- a^2)p+(xy-az\tan \alpha)q=xz-ay\cot \alpha$ passing through the curve $x^2+y^2=a^2$, $z=0$.

Comment: please, some effort

Answer (score 0):

$$(x^2- a^2)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+(xy-az\tan(\alpha))\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=xz-ay\cot(\alpha) \tag 1$$
One can get rid of the sinusoidal functions. Let :
$$z(x,y)=\cot(\alpha)u(x,y)$$
Eq.$(1)$ is transformed into :
$$(x^2- a^2)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+(xy-au)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=xu-ay \tag 2$$
The system of characteristic ODEs is :
$$\frac{dx}{x^2-a^2}=\frac{dy}{xy-au}=\frac{du}{xu-ay}$$
First family of characteristic curves :

$\frac{dx}{x^2-a^2}=\frac{xdx+ydy-udu}{x(x^2-a^2)+y(xy-au)-u(xu-ay)}=\frac{xdx+ydy-udu}{x\big(x^2+y^2-u^2\big)-a^2}$

$\frac{xdx}{x^2-a^2}=\frac{xdx+ydy-udu}{\big(x^2+y^2-u^2\big)-a^2} \quad\implies\quad \ln|x^2-a^2|=\ln|x^2+y^2-u^2-a^2|+$constant.

Equation of the first characteristic curves : $\quad \frac{x^2+y^2-u^2-a^2}{x^2-a^2}=c_1$

I let take it from here. Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for the solution procedure. I have also tried with the multipliers $(0,y \cot \alpha, z\tan \alpha)$ and obtained the first solution. I am trying for the second but I couldn't get the solution. If possible you may give idea to get the same. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No need for a second solution. The above first one suffises to find the equation of the surface satisfying the specified condition.